# Keep track of execution time in a bash script and terminate current command if it takes too long

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I'm trying to create a bash script to download files en masse from a certain website.

Their download links are sequential - e.g. it's just id=1, id=2, id=3 all the way up to 660000.  The only requirement is that you have to be logged in, which makes this a bit harder.  Oh, and the login will randomly time out after a few hours so I have to log back in.

Here's my current script, which works well about 99% of the time.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd downloads

for i in `seq 1 660000`
do
 lastname=""
 echo "Downloading file $i"
 echo "Downloading file $i" >> _downloadinglog.txt

 response=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} -b _cookies.txt -c _cookies.txt --silent --output /dev/null  "[sample URL to make sure cookie is still logged in]")

 if ! [ $response -eq 200 ]

 then
  echo "Cookie didn't work, trying to re-log in..."
  curl -d "userid=[USERNAME]" -d "pwd=[PASSWORD]" -b _cookies.txt -c _cookies.txt --silent --output /dev/null "[login URL]"
  response=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} -b _cookies.txt -c _cookies.txt --silent --output /dev/null  "[sample URL again]")
  if ! [ $response -eq 200 ]
  then
   echo "Something weird happened?? Response code $response. Logging in didn't fix issue, fix then resume from $(($i - 1))"
   echo "Something weird happened?? Response code $response. Logging in didn't fix issue, fix then resume from $(($i - 1))" >> _downloadinglog.txt
   exit 0
  fi
  echo "Downloading file $(($i - 1)) again incase cookie expiring caused it to fail"
  echo "Downloading file $(($i - 1)) again incase cookie expiring caused it to fail" >> _downloadinglog.txt
  lastname=$(curl --write-out %{filename_effective} -O -J -b _cookies.txt -c _cookies.txt "[URL to download files]?id=$(($i - 1))")
  echo "id $(($i - 1)) = $lastname" >> _downloadinglog.txt
  lastname=""
  echo "Downloading file $i"
  echo "Downloading file $i" >> _downloadinglog.txt
 fi
 lastname=$(curl --write-out %{filename_effective} -O -J -b _cookies.txt -c _cookies.txt "[URL to download files]?id=$i")
 echo "id $i = $lastname" >> _downloadinglog.txt
done
```

So basically what I have it doing is attempting to download a random file before moving to the next file in the set.  If the download fails, we assume the login cookie is no longer valid and tell curl to log me back in.

This works great, and I was able to get several thousand files from it.  But what would happen is - either my router goes down for a second or two, or THEIR site goes down for a minute or two, and curl will just sit there thinking it's downloading for hours.  I once came back to it literally spending 24 hours on the same file.  It doesn't seem to have the ability to know if the transfer timed out in the middle - only if it can't START the transfer.

I know there are ways to terminate execution of a command if you combine it with "sleep", but since this has to be "smart" and restart from where it left off, I can't just kill the whole script.

Any suggestions?  I'm open to using something other than curl if I can use it to login via a terminal command.

Comment: A straightforward way to do it is to set up what amounts to an event loop and spawn the commands as sub-shells.  In your loop, periodically check if tasks have complete and, if necessary, terminate them if too much time has passed.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer You probably mean _background jobs_ (started with control operator `&` at the end of the command), not _subshells_.

Comment: I don't know that you can do this with shell scripts, but it would be totally  straightforward with python and requests.

Comment: Well, the issue here is that I have to have it actually retry the download if it fails.  Sorta like the "cookie didn't work" part, only instead it would say "download timed out" and retry from i-1.  That's the hard part, getting it to work with the rest of the logic!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the curl options `--connect-timeout` or `--max-time` .
`--max-time` should be your pick.

From manual :

> --max-time
>
> Maximum time in seconds that you allow the whole operation to take. This is useful for preventing your batch jobs from hanging for hours due to slow networks or links going down. Since 7.32.0, this option accepts decimal values, but the actual timeout will decrease in accuracy as the specified timeout increases in decimal precision. See also the --connect-timeout option.
>
> If this option is used several times, the last one will be used.

Then capture the result of the command in a var and process further based on the result.